# Why is std::forward necessary for checking if a type can be converted to another without narrowing in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

To make a concept checking if a type can be converted without narrowing to another, it is proposed [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0870r4.html) to make it using std::forward and std::type_identity_t like this:

```
template<class T, class U>
concept __construct_without_narrowing = requires (U&& x) {
    { std::type_identity_t<T[]>{std::forward<U>(x)} } -> T[1];
};
```

I understand from it why something like this:

```
To{std::declval<From>()}
```

gives incorrect results, but when i try to simplify it using another idea in the paper, writing just

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept WithoutNarrowing = 
requires (From x) {
    {(To[1]){x}} 
    ->std::same_as<To[1]>;
};
```

It seems to give the same results. What circumstances have to occur for it to give different result? Or is it equivalent? For what reason is std::forward used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual approach for type traits like this that involve some kind of function/constructor argument.

`U` is the type from which `T` is supposed to be constructed, but if we want to discuss the construction we also need to consider the value category of the argument. It may be an lvalue or a rvalue and this can affect e.g. which constructor is usable.

The idea is that we map the rvalue argument case to a non-reference `U` or rvalue reference `U` and the lvalue argument case to a lvalue reference `U`, matching the mapping of expressions in `decltype` and of return types with value categories in function call expressions.

Then, by the reference collapsing rules, `U&&` will be a lvalue reference if the constructor argument is a lvalue and otherwise a rvalue reference. Then using `std::forward` means that the actual argument we give to the construction will indeed be a lvalue argument when `U` was meant to represent one and a rvalue argument otherwise.

Your approach using `{(To[1]){x}}` doesn't use the forwarding and so would always only test whether construction from a lvalue can be done without narrowing, which is not what is expected if e.g. `U` is a non-reference.

---

Your approach is further incorrect because `(To[1]){x}` is not valid syntax in standard C++. If `X` is a type you can have `X{x}` or `(X)x`, but not `(X){x}`. The last syntax is part of C however and called a *compound literal* there. For that reason a C++ compiler may support it as an extension to C++. That's why the original implementation uses the round-about way with `std::type_identity_t`.

---

The implementation seems to also be written for an earlier draft of C++20 concepts. It is now not possible to use types to the right of `->` directly for a requirement. Instead a concept, i.e. `-> std::same_as<T[1]>`, must be used as in your suggested implementation.

Answer (score 0):

well there is difference between `(U u)`, `(U& u)` and `(U&& u)` that `std::forward` is supposed to preserve. in case of `(U u)` the type has to have defined a copy constructor (since `(U u)` basically means "pass a copy of")